# Backbone, Node, Session validation, my method working, but tell me whether it is correct or not

Tags: session, node.js, backbone.js, express

I used this at the beginning :

```js
var app = express.createServer(
  express.cookieParser(),
  express.session({ secret: 'somesecretword' })
);
```

Below code is a sample code to get user details with uname as the key.

I call this code from backbone model's url, by calling model.fetch().

```js
app.get('/user/:uname/', function (req, res) {

  var uname=req.params.uname;
  if(!req.session.user)   // check if logged in
  res.send("Not Logged In");

  return UserModel.find({uname : uname},function(err, user) {
    if (!err) {
      return res.send(user);
    } else {
      return res.send(err);
    }
  });
});
```

So, here I wrote the code for validating session directly in the above get method.

What if I have many such methods? Do I have to write the same thing in every method, or is there any controller in Node that does this work?

For example, show me a controller that validates for the paths "/user" , means "/user/anythinghere/" should be validated automatically or show me some other better way.

Answer (score 2):

What you are needing is some sort of middleware to pass with the app.get method. I can't exactly re-write your code block as I myself am still learning Node.js how ever this from the Express documentation (modified a bit to try and suit your needs)

```
function requireAuth(req, res, next) {
  if(req.session.user) {
    next();
  } else {
    next(new Error('Failed to load user ' + req.params.id));
  }
}

app.get('/user/edit/:id', requireAuth, function(req, res){
  res.send('you can see this because you are authed');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Not requiring auth on homepage');
});
```

The documentation here explains it better then I can:

http://expressjs.com/guide.html#route-middleware

I hope this can be of some help. :) If anything, I myself just learnt something new answering this, so thanks :D

Comment: You are right ,thanks for the answer but what u mean is , we have to call that "requireAuth" in every definition of app.get, right ? Can anyone answer without using that , i mean, i want to know whether its possible or not , to do. if possible ,how ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use middleware and put it in a route like this:

```
app.get('/user/edit/:id', requireAuth, function(req, res){
  res.send('you can see this because you are authed');
});
```

or what I do is something like this using a wildcard:

```
app.all("/api/private*", ensureAuthenticated);
```

You can read up more on this here: https://fabianosoriani.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/express-api-on-node-js-with-mysql-auth/