# Passport.js: accessing user when using backbone

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, pug, passport.js

I'm using passport.js in a node.js app to get OAuth working (awesome!), but now, I'm having problem with one thing.

I'm using backbone.js on client side, to create the views (I'm trying to create a SinglePage app...), and the only way I'm thinking about getting user id or something like that in backbone is creating first an input-hidden in jade templates and then passing it to the constructor in my backbone views.... or just assign the value to a javascript variable and passing it to the router that manages all the views, and pass it to every view that need it

I think it's not a good idea, and there might be better options!

How would you do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done anything in Backbone yet, but there are solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160465/backbone-node-session-validation-my-method-working-but-tell-me-whether-it-is), [here](http://blog.opperator.com/post/15671431847/backbone-js-sessions-and-authentication) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808655/backbone-js-handling-if-a-user-is-logged-in-or-not) already. As long as you get the session id somewhere, you can retrieve the session with the [cookie](https://npmjs.org/package/cookie)-package (cookie has been outsourced from connect-utils):

```
if(handshakeData.headers.cookie) {
  c = cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie);
  sid = connect.utils.parseSignedCookie(c['connect.sid'], 'keyboard cat');
  redis.get('sess:'+sid, function(error, result) {
    session = JSON.parse(result);
    handshakeData.uid = session.passport.user;
    callback(null, true);
  });
```